# Vlc.DotNet commands with c# without installing VLC

Tags: c#, .net, command, vlc, libvlc

I have a certain command that I use, which is calling the VLC exe file (which means it has to be installed in a given machine in order to work).

I have found a package that seems to contain the features of VLC, just not sure about how to use the command with it. I want to set a command, then execute it from the code (I am using C#). Is that possible?

The name of the nuget I installed that seemed to be the most popular is "Vlc.DotNet". It seems to allow creating an instance of a player, play/pause etc. but I would like to run a command and execute it. For example, a command that I use with the help of the installed executable such as '"vlcExePath" "command"', will perform some action such as encode a video for example. I would like to have that without VLC being installed. If there is any way of doing so, I would like to know it.

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific 'what package' and show us what you tried until now? Eg. reference from visual studio and so on...

Comment: just edited it.

Comment: Installed libvlc? [See here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/288)

Comment: I believe it has it. In the description it says: ".Net API to use the audio/video capabilities of the VLC libraries."

Comment: No that is the description for Vlc.DotNet itself. Please see my link where the installation is discussed. Not sure if the nuget package is already available

Answer (score 0):

Install https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/3.0.0-alpha3

And pass your CLI option as `vlcMediaPlayerOptions` to Vlc.DotNet (which will forward them to libvlc).